# Eclipse code editor colour schemes

Tags: eclipse

Is there an Eclipse equivalent of http://studiostyl.es/ or some other way to set code editor colour schemes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer on Google: http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

So I guess the answer is yes.